# Вертикальная полоса в DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-navigation-drawer

Хочу сделать анимацию на вытаскивание `NavigationDrawer`, которая на тот же уровень сдвигала бы содержимое экрана. Поиск по просторам Интернета дал ответ, сделал листенер в `mDrawerToggle`. Но обнаружилось, что при вытаскивание Drawer'а справа по краю экрана появляется вертикальная белая полоса, под которую уползает весь контент, хотя требуется чтобы кнопка-гамбургер была видна и готова к нажатию (закрывает Drawer). Как можно получить доступ к разметке этой полосы и/или убрать её?

Речь об этом

[image: Полоса слева]

Comment: может быть https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu это то что вам нужно?

Comment: Немного нерационально уже перелопачивать всю стуктуру и подключать стороннюю библиотеку. Ведь надо то разобрать один элемент. Если это возможно, конечно

Comment: разобрался, тут больше мой косяк. Засетил ширину для DrawerLayout меньше чем ширина экрана, а надо было для Drawer'а, И в функции анимации надо было учитывать ширину drawer'а, а не drawerlayout

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Изначально mDrawerToggle выглядел так (код для анимации вытаскивания Drawer, найденный на английском стаке)

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                Drawer,
                R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                float moveFactor = (Drawer.getWidth() * slideOffset);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    frame.setTranslationX(moveFactor);
                }
                else {
                    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(lastTranslate, moveFactor, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                    anim.setDuration(0);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                    frame.startAnimation(anim);

                    lastTranslate = moveFactor;
                }
            }
        };

        Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Здесь frame это контент, каоторый должен сдвигаться вправо, а Drawer это DrawerLayout. КОд работал, но "гамбургер" уползал за край экрана. Я добавил лог в код mDrawerToggle, чтобы выяснить, что такое Drawer.getWidth() и slideOffset, выяснилось, что этот код вызывается постоянно по мере вытягивания NavigationDrawer. При этом ширина DrawerLayout равна ширине экрана, что логично, а slideOffset это "коэффициэнт вытащености DrawerLayout". Собственно тут то я и сделал вертикальную полосу, потому что первая мысль, которая пришла в голову была уменьшить ширину DrawerLayout. Почему то я решил, что "гамбургер" при этом останется на экране. Вертикальной полосой оказалась разница между шириной экрана и шириной главного Layout текущей разметки. Дальше сделал то, что было логичнее всего, стал учитывать в onDrawerSlide ширину не главного Layout, а вылезающего NavigationDrawer, и в результате получил тот результат, который и ожидал. Надеюсь не заминусуете за глупость :)

Comment: Через 2 дня сможете свой вопрос отметить "принятым".